# Differentiate staticCards & Dynamiccards

Tags: javascript, jquery

From Json API, data are read and displayed in the HTML.

User can also add custom articles which are stored as staticCards object inside script tag.

Now i wanted to find the HTML which is rendering the staticCards and add a class only to those articles.

How can i differentiate ? staticCards & Dynamiccards (directly rendered from JSON API)

```js
var staticCards = [{
    "cardLayout": "comms-double-image",
    "cardLabel": "STORY",
    "cardTitle": "households receive their share of $3.4 billion",
    "cardDate": "05 April 2017",
    "fileReference": "/content/dam/caas/newsroom/images/2016-09-15-newsroom-habib-spoons-banner-image.png",
    "imageFocus": "image-centre-focus",
    "cardLinkURL": "#",
    "cardLinkDTM": "data-tracker-id=\"cards_1_1\" data-tracker-type=\"button\" data-tracker_ei=\"cards_1_1\" "
}]
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="comms-double-image">

    <article class="card card-double cvp comms image" data-tags="">

        <a href="{{link}}" class="link" data-tracker-id="{{trackerId}}" data-tracker-type="{{trackerType}}" data-tracker_ei="{{trackerEI}}">

            <div class="mobile-wrapper">

                <div class="background-container" style="background-image : url({{image}});">

                    <h4 class="eta font-low-impact">{{label}}</h4>

                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <time datetime="{{date-time}}">{{date-time}}</time>
                    {{#xif "this.title > 45"}}
                        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                    {{else}}
                        <h3 class="delta">{{truncate title 55}}</h3>
                    {{/xif}}

                    <p class="cta">{{link-desc}}</p>

                </div>

            </div>

        </a>

    </article>

</script>
```

Comment: take a look into setTimeout: `setTimeout(function() { //do some code }, 1500);` 1500 = miliseconds (time is done in ms)

Comment: no it dosen't work!!

Comment: does it show anything in the console?

Comment: also did you separate the lines? The above shouldn't be one line - the `//` will break it on one line as it will treat the rest as a comment